# How to use dynamic require in Remix?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

In a Remix `action`, I use a dynamic `require` to retrieve different JSON files:

```js
export async function action({ request }: { request: Request }) {
  const body = await request.formData();
  const country = body.get("country");

  const cities = require(`~/cities_by_country/${country}.json`);

  return cities;
}
```

This produces and "Application Error": `Error: Cannot find module '~/cities_by_country/Afghanistan.json'`

It turns out that the dynamic `require` is the issue. Hardcoding the country like this works:

```
const cities = require(`~/cities_by_country/Afghanistan.json`);
```

I read that adding `"module": esnext` (or es2020 or es2022) to tsconfig.json would enable dynamic imports, at least for React. I tried it but got the same results.

I've read these docs as well to no avail:

- [asset url imports](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#asset-url-imports)
- [data-loading](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/data-loading)
- [resource routes](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes)

What am I missing?

Comment: My guess: The Remix compiler (using esbuild) will try to bundle imports, but needs imports to be static to do so, since the bundling happens at build time.

You could have a file that imports each country's JSON statically, exports each as the country name, and then `import * as cities_by_country from "cities_by_country"` so that you can access as `cities_by_country[country_name]`. That way the Remix compiler _should_ bundle your JSON files as part of the server bundle.

Comment: @PedroCattori I postponed this feature for now but this sounds reasonable.